# How do I print jasmine test spec in afterEach?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to print the jasmine test spec name (using protractor) for the 2 tests in the afterEach block. My spec file looks like this:
test.e2e-spec.ts

```js
describe('Tests', function() {
  it('Passing', function () {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  });
  it('Failing', function () {
    expect(false).toBeTruthy();
  });

  afterEach(function(done){
    console.log("Test Name: "+jasmine.results.spec.fullName);
  });

});
```

I run the spec file using a config file.

I am getting a `TS2339: Property 'results' does not exist on type 'typeof jasmine'.`
How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

`results` doesn't exists in `jasmine`. You can add custom reporter to solve your problem.

`specDone` is invoked when an `it` and its associated `beforeEach` and `afterEach` functions have been run.

So, a simple solution would be:

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
    specDone: function(result) {
      console.log('Test Name:'+result.fullName);
    }
});

describe('Tests', function() {
  it('Passing', function () {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  });
  it('Failing', function () {
    expect(false).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

For more details, refer: [Jasmine Custom Reporter](https://jasmine.github.io/2.3/custom_reporter.html)

Comment: You answered me to other question with your answer. Thanks! haha